# Calculate how many people have never paid for a class using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

[image]I have a problem where I can't figure out how many people have filled a form on the website and never paid for a class.

There are many classes and sometimes the same people fill out the form for one class and then don't pay. And later they pay for another class.

How do I eliminate the people who have paid for one of the classes.

Below is the query i use to show the duplicates.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) id, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Class_Code) Classes, GROUP_CONCAT(Payment_Complete) Paid, COUNT(*) c FROM studentDetails GROUP BY Name HAVING c > 1
```

Comment: please share the schema

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Payment details shouldn't be in the student table. You should create a separate table for payments with student id, class id, date paid, amount paid, etc.

Comment: @Mike is right it shouldn't have payment details !!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

take a status and count column in database table which will show the paid status or unpaid status 
like

```
  $query = "select * from table_name where status= 'paid'";
  $st = $connection->prepare($query);
  $st->excute();
  $result = $st->fetchAll();
  $connection = null;
```

then check everytime if the status is paid update it to null with increase your  count with every affected row update of  status services  paid by the customer

Comment: Please suggest a better one!

Comment: @Strawberry but its simple and time complexity is also manageable